# Receiving 0 size messages while using ZMQ and protobuf

Tags: c++, serialization, zeromq, protocol-buffers

I am trying to set up a basic communication system between client and server using ZMQ. I am using protobuf for the message format.
My problem is when I send the message from client the message size is 34 but the message size received  on the server is 0.

Following is my code;

Client.cpp

```
tutorial::Person person;
person.set_id(1234);
person.set_name("john");
person.set_email("john@mxyz.com");
person.set_phonenumber("12345678");


zmq::context_t context (1); //  Prepare our context and socket
zmq::socket_t socket (context, ZMQ_PAIR);

std::cout << "Connecting to server…" << std::endl;
int linger = 0;// ms
socket.setsockopt(ZMQ_LINGER, &linger, sizeof(linger));
socket.connect ("tcp://127.0.0.1:20000");

std::string msg_str;
person.SerializeToString(&msg_str);
std::cout << "Size of message string is "<< msg_str.size()<<std::endl;
zmq::message_t request (msg_str.size());
memcpy ((void *) request.data (), msg_str.c_str(), msg_str.size());
std::cout << "Sending Person data ..." << std::endl;
socket.send (request);

socket.close();

google::protobuf::ShutdownProtobufLibrary();
return 0;
```

Server.cpp :

```
zmq::context_t context(1); //  Prepare our context and socket
zmq::socket_t socket(context, ZMQ_PAIR);
int linger = 0; // ms
socket.setsockopt(ZMQ_LINGER, &linger, sizeof(linger));
socket.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:20000");
while (true)
 {
    zmq::message_t request;
    int recieved = socket.recv(&request);
    std::string msg(static_cast<char*>(request.data()),request.size());
    std::cout<<"Size of message recieved is "<<  msg.size()<<std::endl;
    tutorial::Person person;
    person.ParseFromString(msg);
    std::string text_str1;
    google::protobuf::TextFormat::PrintToString(person, &text_str1);
}
socket.close();
```

Output of Client is :

```
Size of message string is 34
```

Output of server is :

```
Size of message received is 0
```

I have tried tried switching to ParseToArray also but it did not help.
Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure recv() did not return with an error? You don't check the return value.

Comment: I just checked the return value of received is 1 . But I am not sure why.

Comment: Looking up the error base , it says EPERM which means operation not permitted.

Comment: @VishalRawat `zmq::socket_t::recv()` returns `true` (1) if it succeeded, `false` (0) otherwise (it does not return an error code). So it sounds like it is succeeding.

Comment: @KentonVarda the errno-base.h has the following macros : #define EPERM   1 /* Operation not permitted */
#define ENOENT   2 /* No such file or directory */
#define ESRCH   3 /* No such process */
#define EINTR   4 /* Interrupted system call */
#define EIO   5 /* I/O error */
and so on...  The documentation of zmq_recv [http://api.zeromq.org/2-1:zmq-recv] states this "The zmq_recv() function shall return zero if successful. Otherwise it shall return -1 and set errno to one of the values defined below."

Comment: And I was unable to find any helpful resources which says how to solve EPERM or give further information about the same.

Comment: @VishalRawat You aren't calling `zmq_recv()`, you are calling `zmq::socket_t::recv()`. According to the docs, it returns `bool`. http://api.zeromq.org/2-1:zmq-cpp

Comment: @kenton Than ks for the comments.  It could be the issue but I have solved it with another way. Actually I installed libzmq lib , but later when I switched to libzmq3-dev it worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it with another way. Actually earlier I installed libzmq lib , but later when I switched to libzmq3-dev it worked for me.

Comment: I have the same issue but on windows. I am using nodejs/zmq/win7 64bit.Any idea how to resolve this bug?

Comment: I know this question is old (three years) but your solution is a bit worrisome.  You seem to have "fixed" the problem by altering the timing or ordering of something.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem; what I found is that the `zmq::message_t` had to go out of scope OR `rebuild` needed to be called.

For example, if the publisher looked like this.

```
        zmq::message_t msg(3);
        memcpy(msg.data(), "abc", 3);
        while (1 == 1) {
            pubSocket.send(msg);
            sleep(1);
        }
```

The subscriber would receive messages of zero length.  If the code was changed to

```
        while (1 == 1) {
            zmq::message_t msg(3);
            memcpy(msg.data(), "abc", 3);

            pubSocket.send(msg);
            sleep(1);
        }
```

OR

```
        zmq::message_t msg(3);
        memcpy(msg.data(), "abc", 3);
        while (1 == 1) {
            pubSocket.send(msg);
            msg.rebuild(3);
            sleep(1);
        }
```

Then the subscriber would receive a 3-byte message.

Comment: For future readers of this question, note that `message::rebuild()` no longer exists.  Cf. this [github issue](https://github.com/zeromq/azmq/issues/115).