# ZeroMQ file transfer, chunk by chunk, in a PUSH / PULL socket-archetype is not working - why?

Tags: node.js, zeromq, git-bash

An image file is transferred from a ZeroMQ server to a ZeroMQ client through a **`PUSH/PULL`** Scaleable Formal Communication Pattern ( using a socket interface ), being sent chunk by chunk (in 1024 bytes). I do not get the last 9KB of any file I send, as the incoming message length, on the client side of the ZeroMQ `PULL` socket is zero!

**Update:** The same was tried with a **`ROUTER/DEALER`** pattern too. The same problem persists. For the last few chunk transfers, incoming message sizes becomes zero (though the server was sending the chunks)

I came across this - [Receiving 0 size messages while using ZMQ and protobuf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38420559/receiving-0-size-messages-while-using-zmq-and-protobuf) question which seems relevant. 
I am using git bash on windows/0mq bindings/visual studio 2015.

Any ideas on how to resolve this will be helpful.

Comment: Would you mind to present the full **MCVE**, as the StackOverflow policy encourages to? >>> http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sure, sorry about that.But i think this problem may not related to zmq. It is related to appending the chunks to a file.I have tried using fs.writeStream in append mode to no avail.I will update this thread on further verification.Thank you.

Comment: A missing fileIO `flush` / `commit` ? May disambiguate using inRAM-stored objects and explicitly check source / target `len()`-s.